# Summing likes from all "shares" of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, share

I have a website with different pages. Each page should have a Like button and a Share button (to Facebook only).

First I didn't find any mention of a Share button in the Facebook Documentation. Can you point me a guide or reference?

However the big problem is that I need to sum likes from all the shares, and the likes on the page too. For example if 10 users clicked on Like on the page. Then some shared to their profile, and someone liked that too, I need to show a total of 10 + the likes on the profiles. Is there a ready-made Facebook API function to do this? Or do I need to track each share and sum manually all the references?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a URL you can use the FQL `link_stat` table to get this data but it seems per URL.

Documentation for the `link_stat` table - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/%27
```

Will give you:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/",
         "normalized_url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/",
         "share_count": 31155,
         "like_count": 12932,
         "comment_count": 17584,
         "total_count": 61671,
         "commentsbox_count": 2,
         "comments_fbid": 405555547748,
         "click_count": 1032
      }
   ]
}
```

Of course using this method you would need to make an API call for each page.

Perhaps someone knows a better approach.

Comment: Does this sum all "link" shares? If so, you're my hero.

Comment: The API call returns a single record worth of data - so I'm assuming that `share_count` is a sum of share actions involving that URL. You could always test it with a URL that isn't publically known (I'm not sure how up-to-date the results are - so if you test, keep that in mind).